# Got an issue with Javascript collision detection

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly new to coding and having some issues with collision detection. We were given a lot of code like this for collision detection for a platformer and it went well when there was a character that walked on tiles that were the same width and height but now I'd had to change it because my current tiles are different widths and heights. Had to turn from TILE to `TILE_X` and `TILE_Y` in my main js file and edit the rest to match.

Sadly for some reason I can't see when going right and down I collide properly but then when I try and go left I collide with thin air a tile away from where I should collide.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Alex Kidd in Miracle World</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="alex.css">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="javascript/howler.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="javascript/level1.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="javascript/map.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="javascript/keyboard.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="javascript/utils.js"></script>    
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="javascript/vector2.js"></script>  
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="javascript/sprite.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="javascript/player.js"></script>   
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="javascript/update.js"></script>   

</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="1024" height="700">This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5</canvas>
    <p>A = Move Left | D = Move Right | Spacebar = Jump</p>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="javascript/main.js"></script>


</body>
</html>

/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
v2.0 | 20110126
License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
display: block;
}
body {
line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
content: '';
content: none;
}
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
}

p {
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 200%;
font-family: arial;
}


var tileX = pixelToTileX(this.position.x);
var tileY = pixelToTileY(this.position.y);
var overlapX = this.position.x % TILE_X;
var overlapY = this.position.y % TILE_Y;

var cell = cellDataAtTileCoord(LAYER_WALKABLE, tileX, tileY);
var cellRight = cellDataAtTileCoord(LAYER_WALKABLE, tileX + 1, tileY);
var cellDown = cellDataAtTileCoord(LAYER_WALKABLE, tileX, tileY + 1);
var cellDiag = cellDataAtTileCoord(LAYER_WALKABLE, tileX + 1, tileY + 1);

if (this.velocity.x > 0) {
        if ((cellRight && !cell) || (cellDiag && !cellDown && overlapY)) {
            this.velocity.x = 0;
            this.position.x = tileToPixelX(tileX);
        }
} else if (this.velocity.x < 0) {
        if ((cell && !cellRight) || (cellDown && !cellDiag && overlapY)) {
                this.velocity.x = 0;
                this.position.x = tileToPixelX(tileX + 1);
        }
}       


function tileToPixelX(tile) {
    return tile * TILE_X;
}

function tileToPixelY(tile) {
    return tile * TILE_Y;
}

function pixelToTileX(pixel) {
    return Math.floor(pixel/TILE_X);
}

function pixelToTileY(pixel) {
    return Math.floor(pixel/TILE_Y);
}

function cellDataAtTileCoord(layers, tileX, tileY) {
    if (tileX < 0 || tileX >= MAP.TILES_WIDE ||tileY < 0) {
        return 1;
    } else if (tileY >= MAP.TILES_HIGH) {
        return 0;
    }
    return cells[layers][tileY][tileX];
}

function cellAtPixelCoord(layer, x, y) {

    if (x < 0 || x > SCREEN_WIDTH || y < 0) {
        return 1;
    } else if (y > SCREEN_HEIGHT) {
        return 0;
    }
    return cellDataAtTileCoord(layers, pixelToTile(x), pixelToTile(y));
}
```

Comment: give html content and css content also

Comment: "my current tiles are different widths and heights" does this mean that the tiles are all the same dimension (e.g. 25x12) but just no longer square (25x25) or do you actually have tiles that have different dimensions from each other?

Comment: Updated with HTML and CSS. I'm new to this so idk what is needed to help but I have like 10 js files and kinda tried to only copy and paste the collision code I was having the issue with. Otherwise it'd be like 4000 lines of code and copy paste doesn't all go into code blocks so I have to spacebar 4 times on every line of code. Also yeah I meant no longer square. The other game I originally got the code for used 35x35 tiles and this is using 32x26.